# get compressed size of webpack modules after uglify

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

After setting up a webpack build with uglify, one wants to know how effectively the modules are being compressed, so it can be optimized.

Is there any tooling for this? I don't see webpack or uglify options that report the module size after compression.

Comment: If you want to know the byte count, why not write a script using [`wc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)?

Comment: Is there a hook where I could inject a script & apply wc? After the compile there's just the concatenated, compressed js w/o module names.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a tool such as https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer :)

It's very helpful for tracking down bloated modules!

Of course don't forget to enable sourcemaps. See https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool